# Fixed sidebar too tall for browser (bottom is getting cut off)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a fixed sidebar that is XXpx tall (Refer to http://www.getskeleton.com/ if you want a visual of what I mean). The sidebar looks exactly the way I want, as long as the height of the browser is bigger than the sidebar. However, when the browser height shrinks below the height of the sidebar, the bottom contents get cut off.

Initially, the sidebar has `position: fixed`, but if the browser gets too small to contain the entire sidebar, I want to change it to `position: aboslute`. Essentially, I'd like to make it so on both page load and any time the user resizes finishes resizing the page it will check to make sure that the bottom content isn't being cut off, then assign the appropriate `position` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
var $sidebar = $('#idOfSidebar')
    ,$w = $(window);
$w.resize(function () { 
  var pos = $w.height() < $sidebar.height()? 'absolute': 'fixed'; 
  $sidebar.css({position: pos});
});
```

Comment: I've never used the `.resize` function... do I need to be worried about performance since this function could potentially be called quite a few times in a resize?

Comment: Yes you should worry. That is why I took all the 'expensive'-ish statements out of the function itself and only used the cached ones inside of it.

Comment: Is there any way I could further optimize this statement? Caching the height of the sidebar seems like a pretty simple one for starters

Comment: Yup. that would be even better. I think this will be fast enough though.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a vertical media query for this, like so (let's say the sidebar is 700px tall.)

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute; 
}

media screen and (min-height:700px) {
    #sidebar { position: fixed; }
}
```

By declaring the absolute position first, you make sure that browsers that don't support media queries will get the absolutely positioned sidebar, which will still be functional.

Comment: very clean solution, but this will not work in older browsers.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm looking for something compatible IE7+ though.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `overflow: auto` for fixed blocks that can be potentially taller than browser`s client height. This can be used as default pure-CSS solution that can work *in conjunction* with JavaScript methods.

Comment: Wouldn't that add a separate scrollbar to the sidebar though?

Comment: Would. It's generally better than inaccessibility of several sidebar elements at all. You can use JavaScript _additionally_ to this, not instead.

Comment: I'll definitely be adding this to my code. Thank you for the suggestion.